# Выборка данных MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, mvc, entity-framework

Имеется таблица в БД

```
Catalogs (
    id    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
    pid   INT            NOT NULL
    title NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
);
```

Можно ли используя Entity Framework получить все child каталоги родителя? 
Например таблица будет выглядеть следующим образом:

- Одежда

  - Верхняя одежда

    - Джинсы
    - Куртки
  - Бельё
- Компьютеры

и нужно получить всех child каталоги родителя "Одежда".

Answer (score 1):

Решить вопрос получилось как-то так.

---

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    public void AllChilds(int id)
    {
        var childs = catrepository.Catalogs.Where(x => x.pid == id)
            .OrderBy(x => x.id);
        foreach(var p in childs)
        {
            dict.Add(p.id, p.title);
            AllChilds(p.id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

На текущий момент у EF нет поддержки рекурсивных запросов, используя CTE (Общее Табличной Выражение).

Проблему можно решить, если использовать **view**. Пример можно посмотреть в статье [Recursive or hierarchical queries using EF Code First and Migrations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Recursive-or-hierarchical-bf43a96e)